# Azure DevOps wait until another build in same CI is done

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

Is there any way of making the build in VSTS/Azure DevOps wait until another build in the same CI is done. I want to be able to use the Hosted agent but be able to do that. I don't want to use my own agent.

Comment: Do you mean if you did 2 pushes one after another so you want one build to run and the second build will wait?

Answer (score 1):

If you create your Azure DevOps Pipelines CI build using YAML, you can do that. Using `dependsOn` will enforce sequential jobs build.

For example:

```
jobs:
- job: Debug
  steps:
  - script: echo hello from the Debug build
- job: Release
  dependsOn: Debug
  steps:
  - script: echo hello from the Release build
```

See also the official doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#dependencies

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Classic way of configuring Azure Pipelines (Not using YAML),

then you may try to add Agent.Name equals "One of the available Agent name" condition in Demands section.
You will find "Demands" section  where you configure Agent Pool in Azure Pipelines.